# How do I create a webcal in php so that user can subscribe to it?

Tags: php, icalendar, vcalendar

I'm creating a resource planner and I want to enable webcal subscribing for the resources. Right now I don't have a clue of how to develop a webcal subscribing system in PHP. Are there any documentions/library or code snippets you can share with me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , there are quite a few i have known of, some good ones that can be of help are

```
http://code.google.com/p/sabredav/
http://www.davical.org/
```

I hope these can be of some help to you in getting started with webcal

Comment: I don't know if this is true. But I have made some research. Can't I just write an .ics file on my server file system and provide the url?  When I update the file it will autoupdate(duration is depending on calendar application) .